# How to use (share) a project wide spellcheck dictionary in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spell-checking

It doesn't make sense to have user dictionaries for multi-developer Eclipse projects, so I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to share a spell-check dictionary with all users.

As you can imagine the checkout and eclipse locations can be different for each user.

Also the dictionary should stay inside project directory because I want to add it to the version control system used by the project.

This question is targeted to the latest released version of Eclipse 3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use project-specific dictionaries in all your projects, you could create a file `.dictionary` at the root of your project, and set the value of the "User defined dictionary" at (`General->Editors->Text Editors->Spelling`) to `${project_loc}/.dictionary`. I don't know how to have BOTH a global dictionary and a project-specific dictionary, as the relevant preference page  allows only one "User defined dictionary".

Note: that there can be some very confusing behavior when you don't have .dictionary files defined in a project. The behavior depends on some hidden cache behavior of the spell-checking implementation and your previous actions, and might be considered an Eclipse bug.

1. If you have just opened Eclipse, go to a project *without* a `.dictionary`, edit some file, and add a spelling to the dictionary, Eclipse will *create* the `.dictionary` file. That is strange because it won't even do that from the main wizard page. You have to create the file manually first before you can specify it.
2. If you were first working in project that *does* have a `.dictionary`, then switch to a different project *without* one, edit a file, and add a spelling, Eclipse will add it to the `.dictionary` in the *original* project!
3. Deleting entires in the dictionary or deleting the dictionary file will not cause the added words to be relabeled as misspelled, regardless of refreshing the project or file. Closing and reaping Eclipse does, however, restore the "misspelled" status of words.

FYI, I am using Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1; Build id: 20110916-0149 on Mac OS X lion.